# Best Practice for structuring files within a node.js project

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am currently trying to get my hands on node more and was wondering about "best practices" when it comes to handling the npm specific files and folders. Specifically the `node_modules`.

**The project in mind has the following aspects:**

- REST API (node / express)
- Front-End (vue / Gatsby)
- Robots (automated tasks, js, cron jobs)
- *App (Flutter), not set-up with node*
- *Documentation (md), not set-up with node*

3 of the 5 components are most likely going to use node_modules at some point. setting up all 3 in seperate folders on it's own is a waste of disk-space since they are sharing quite a few npm packages.

How should these components be set up?

I was thinking of a folder structure like this:

```
project folder
|
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── dot files (.gitignore, ...)
|
└── moduels
    ├── docs
    ├── api
    ├── app
    ├── robots
    └── web
```

Let's say I get started with the `api` using express. does it make sense to relocate the node_modules folder into the parent file structure and would this even work?

if it does should I leave app and docs in the structure even if they are not using any node_modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this might work, I'd argue against "reusing" your `node_modules` between several `modules`. Instead you might consider using something like [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) to be more disk efficient.

Your suggested structure in particular uses a single `package.json` for all, the api, the frontend and the jobs. Consequently, it'll be very hard to separate dependencies between these three components when deploying later. So when you want to deploy these separately (e.g. in a Docker container) you need to use all of your dependencies in all three containers instead of only the ones needed.

Furthermore, you are more or less setup for dependency hell with a single `package.json`. When one of your modules need an other dependency version (maybe directly, maybe transitive) than another module, this will complicate things even more.

Comment: Hi @Jb31, thank you for your response. I haven't actually thought about the aspect of dependency issues. does make sense and it's sure is more annoying. I guess I need a better system to keep track of abondened projects to avoid a pileup on my dev device then :)